# is Elm's List faster than Javascript's Array?

Tags: elm

I'm currently working on a mathematics web app, may need to deal with large array (over 150m elements) and a lot of calculation, compositing with different math function sound a good idea. Thought using a functional style should be a good idea. Based on https://elm-lang.org/news/0.12.1 article, is Elm's built-in `List` and `iteration` is faster than Native javascript?

Note: Performance is the first priority.

Comment: Yes and No. It depends entirely on what you do with it.

Comment: I would recommend to use webassembly with a language like rust for performance. Elm gets compiled to javascript, the only difference is that because of the immutability of data, some aggressive code performance can be applied.

Comment: @glennsl, a little more example? what is the weakness on Elm's `List`, `Dict`, `Set`? Since `ES6` already have `Map`, `Set` or even `Week Map` and `Week Set`.

Comment: Since you're the only one who have any idea what type of data and calculation you're going to do, just write short benchmark to compare them.